# which database is the best for working with single user and read only mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ms-access, sql-server-ce

I should write little app, that will work with single table database in single user mode (only one user will be use it). This user only should view data on read only mode. He shouldn't change any data.

Data is going to be updated physically one time in a month by backup and/or copy past.

Which database is good for this? MS Access, ms sql express, ms sqlce? Application is going to be written on C# Windows Forms. And performance is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I would go for [Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki): fast, easy with full [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) support.

It's easy: no services, no installation, just a file.

It's scallable: can have multiple tables and complicated relations between them, if it's neccessary for you, but do not have `stored-procedures`

Comment: +1 As a note, MS Access can essentially do the forementioned also, so it may come down to personal preference and or previous experience.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you believe ACID transaction support is a benefit in a single-user read-only db application.  Similarly, the scalability issues you mentioned are irrelevant for the OP's use case (*single table database*).

Comment: @HansUp: scallability, yes. I just mantioned it to point out that in the moment of need it's, by the way, remains very good choice that let's you scale out application. What about `ACID` principles need, they are basically the same here then on enterprise application (from top level point of view). Explanation of those concepts can be found on the same post I posted link on. So I don't see a need and space (honestly) to explain *all* that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an OODB is your answer. they are still faster in reading then anytype of SQL database.

I have used [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) and it's pretty amazing what it can do.